# Is it possible to automate creation of an ad-hoc network and/or changing network location on OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, osx-mountain-lion

I use TouchOSC often and when I do I need to create an ad-hoc network between my iPad and Macbook Pro.

For the convenience of not having to go into settings in the OSC clients and changing IP addresses every time I created a separate Location for my ad-hoc network which assigns static IPs for both my iPad and MBP.

However I still have to manually go to Network Preferences to change my location and then also manually create the Ad-Hoc network every time. The settings I used last time are not remembered so I have to choose the password again etc.

Is there any way to automate this process so I can quickly switch between my ad-hoc network and connection to a regular wifi router?